# Why I can't start a windows CMD from Gitbash with a command?

Tags: git, cmd

I try to start a CMD on windows from Gitbash with passing a command to be executed. But it is not working.

Example: `cmd /K dir`

Why is that not working as it only starts the CMD without any command? The help is working (`cmd /?`)

**SOLUTION: Thanks ElpieKay**

> Use cmd //K dir. Reference superuser.com/a/1413116/1243092.

Comment: Why the requirement to do that *from Gitbash*? If I may.

Comment: Use `cmd //K dir`. Reference https://superuser.com/a/1413116/1243092.